# AngularJS upload onto Sinatra with CORS - blocks first couple POST requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, sinatra, cors

I've faced quite a strange bug.
I have an angular app which uses sinatra as a backend. Backend is hosted on different server so I made a CORS between them.
I works fine for all POST, GET and other requests. But when I try to upload an image - sometimes (only sometimes) I get a "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test-backend.dev/upload/image/. Origin http://test-frontend.dev:9003 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error. For example, I can try to upload the same image 5 times. 4 times it will fail and on the 5th time it will be uploaded successfully. Sometimes it uploads without errors in the first time and sometimes it takes me 20 requests to get a pass one... The error happens more ofter with files bigger than 600kb and almost never happens with small images.

That's a some code for Sinatra backend:

```
configure do
  #To enable cross domain requests
  enable :cross_origin

  set :allow_origin, :any
  set :allow_methods, [:head, :get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
  set :allow_credentials, true
  set :max_age, "86400"
  set :allow_headers, ['*', 'Content-Type', 'Origin', 'Accept', 'X-Requested-With', 'x-xsrf-token']
  set :expose_headers, ['Content-Type']

  disable :protection
  #set :protection, :origin_whitelist => ['http://localhost:9003/'] #btw, that line doesn't work somehow, so I commented it and disabled all the protection for test purposes

  enable :logging

end

#AngularJS sends option request before any other request. These lines properly manage that
options "/*" do
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] ="accept, authorization, origin, content-type, X-PINGOTHER"
  "*"
end

#example of always working request
post '/layer/:layer_id' do
  @updated_layer = JSON.parse(request.body.string)
  @layer = PageLayer.where(id: params[:layer_id]).take!

  @updated_layer.each do |k, v|
    @layer[k] = v
  end
  @layer.save
end

#That request gives me error sometimes
post '/upload/image/' do
  #Getting image id from request
  id = params.keys[0]

  @layer = PageLayer.where(id: id).take!
  @layer.original_upload = params[id.to_s]
  @layer.save
  json @layer
end
```

AngularJS code:

```
#That code to manage $http requests which works fine
lgFrontApp.config ["$httpProvider", ($httpProvider) ->
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"]
]
#And that one is the part of upload plugin: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload (I also tried to use another one, same error sometimes)    
xhr.open('POST', item.url, true);

angular.forEach(item.headers, function (value, name) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader(name, value);
});

xhr.send(form);
```

Just in case, sinatra logs:

```
#Gets all the POST requests, no eror. But once I've spotted IO error. once.
[Thu Sep 05 2013 10:13:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)] INFO [127.0.0.1] POST lg-angular.dev /upload/image/
[Thu Sep 05 2013 10:13:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)] INFO [127.0.0.1] POST lg-angular.dev /upload/image/
[Thu Sep 05 2013 10:13:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)] INFO [127.0.0.1] POST lg-angular.dev /upload/image/
[Thu Sep 05 2013 10:13:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)] INFO [127.0.0.1] GET lg-angular.dev /uploads/image/lac_app4.jpg
#Another log, No errors as well
[Thu Sep 05 2013 10:13:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)] WARNING 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2013 10:13:10] "POST /upload/image/ " 200 1863 2.7447
```

While writing the post I realised that probably, since XMLHttprequest is a bit different from $http, It could make a non-cors request. But simetimes it still work... I have no idea how to fix it. And why it fails only sometimes?

Comment: What is the browser's console logging during this?  I don't see the OPTIONS requests for the preflight in the sinatra logs

Comment: I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test-backend.dev/upload/image/. Origin http://test-frontend.dev:9003 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." in the console

Comment: I assume you are using Chrome.  Due to a bug, you cannot see the server response code returned.  Switch to Firefox w/ firebug just for this.  I believe your problem has something to do on the back-end (seeing how it happens for larger files).  An error may be causing the response headers to not be correctly set and a 500 may be returned.  Firebug will show the response that failed CORS where Chrome will not.

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea!

Comment: @atem_g if you found solution to this please post here.